# Derby Database insertion error

Tags: java, mysql, database, derby

I am writing a code it displays output on output screen well. But when i linked data base to it it gives error of some type which i search a lot on Google but can't got help.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test{
    public ArrayList lines=new ArrayList();// global list contain <item>.......</item>

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test obj= new Test();

       /* String proxy="172.16.4.7";    //proxy address
        String port= "1117";    //proxy port
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost" , proxy);   //setting proxy
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port); //setting proxy port
       */ 
        URL url = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/geo/GiKR");  //geo url
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        line=in.readLine(); //skiping first line of xml version
        line= in.readLine();

        if (line.contains("<item>")) {
           while(line.contains("<item>")) {
              line = obj.extractItem(line); //extraction <item>a nd </item> from origional news feed

           }

        }
    }
String extractItem(String line){
    int start=0, end=0,length=0;
    start= line.indexOf("<item>");
    end= line.indexOf("</item>");
    length= line.length();
    try{
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/NewsFinal";
    String uName="ashfaq";
    String pass="pakistan";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, pass );
    Statement stmt= con.createStatement();

    //lines.add(line.substring(start+6, end));
    String item=line.substring(start+6, end+7);
    //System.out.println(item);
    //String query="INSERT INTO ITEMS2(ITEM) VALUES(" + "'"+item+"'"+")";
    String query="insert into ITEMS(ITEMDATA) values("+"'" + item + "'"+")";
     stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    catch(SQLException err)
    {System.out.println(err.getMessage());}

   //System.out.println(line.substring(start+6, end+7)); //strat+6 to remove item tag, start+13 removes item and title tag
    return line.substring(0,start) + line.substring(end+6,length);
    }

}
```

Here is the output generated by it:

```
run:
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 318.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 330.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 342.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 318.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 330.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 326.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 351.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 319.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 299.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 328.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 307.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 331.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 334.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 319.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 334.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 307.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 325.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 301.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 312.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 306.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 327.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 342.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 333.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 338.
Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 329.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

in the function `extractItem(String line)`, when i uncomment

```
System.out.println(item);
```

it displays output well but cant insert in data base which i created with it.

Database is going well i insert data in it from gui and it worked and also from execute command but don't know why this error arise.

Comment: Have you figured out your question? Are you still having troubles?

Comment: Yeah i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting quotes around an arbitrary string is not going to be enough to make it valid as a VALUE if it contains another quote and leaves you wide open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Use a `PreparedStatement` and set the value in that.

You are also creating a new `Connection` and `Statement` for every item and not closing any of them.